# XSLT Template - text output file Using in

Tags: xslt

Below The sample XSLT Code

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="(TargetBonus &gt;= 0)"><xsl:value-of select="TargetBonus"/></xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>Main</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Above logic I am getting Error like:

> Cannot convert string "" to double

I am not able to find the exact issue

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty `<TargetBonus>` element in your input. This will cause the test `TargetBonus >= 0` to fail with a type conversion error.

Convert to number explicitly.

```
<xsl:when test="number(TargetBonus) &gt;= 0]">...</xsl:when>
```

This will turn any invalid values (including the empty string) into `NaN`, and then the comparison will be possible. `NaN >= 0` will result in `false`, which probably is what you expect.